# Admin - Handle data before creating or updating a post, page or custom post

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin, admin

I need to make some checks of the aggregated data in a page form, a post and a custom post, before these are created or updated, "if it is possible to do it with specific taxonomy", and if the user's information is not correct, we avoid that the creation or update of these is done.

*I appreciate your help very much, please.*